# How to use TwitterUtils in Spark shell?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to use the twitterUtils in the Spark Shell (where they are not available by default).

I've added the following to `spark-env.sh`:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH="/disk.b/spark-master-2014-07-28/external/twitter/target/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

I can now execute

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
```

without an error in the shell, which would not be possible without added the jar to the classpath ("error: object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming").
However, I will get an error when executing this in the Spark shell:

```
scala> val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext =
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@6e78177b

scala> val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, "twitter.txt")
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in TwitterUtils.class refers to
term twitter4j in package <root> which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling
TwitterUtils.class.
```

What am I missing? Do I have to import another jar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, you need the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/) JARs in addition to the `spark-streaming-twitter` one you already have. Specifically, [the Spark devs suggest using Twitter4J version 3.0.3](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/What-version-of-twitter4j-should-I-use-with-Spark-Streaming-td9352.html).

After you download the correct JARs, you'll want to pass them to the shell via the `--jars` flag. I think you can also do this via `SPARK_CLASSPATH` as you've done.

Here's how I did it on a Spark EC2 cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/spark/lib
mkdir twitter4j

# Get the Spark Streaming JAR.
curl -O "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10/1.0.0/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.0.0.jar"

# Get the Twitter4J JARs. Check out http://twitter4j.org/archive/ for other versions.
TWITTER4J_SOURCE=twitter4j-3.0.3.zip
curl -O "http://twitter4j.org/archive/$TWITTER4J_SOURCE"
unzip -j ./$TWITTER4J_SOURCE "lib/*.jar" -d twitter4j/
rm $TWITTER4J_SOURCE

cd
# Point the shell to these JARs and go!
TWITTER4J_JARS=`ls -m /root/spark/lib/twitter4j/*.jar | tr -d '\n'`
/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --jars /root/spark/lib/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.0.0.jar,$TWITTER4J_JARS
```

Comment: this recipe does not work for me using spark 1.6. I downloaded every jar from this curl operation, and when i try to start the spark-shell, i got this:http://pastebin.com/CKQqXMDz

Comment: @aironman - Spark has changed a lot since I wrote this answer. If you are 1) able to successfully run Spark without these Twitter libraries, and 2) not able to boil your problem down further, I recommend asking a new question. The trace you posted doesn't give me any clues as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you could do other than manually adding dependencies of dependencies (which will soon become a nightmare if you start including a lot of jars), is create a dummy sbt project, add the sbt-assembly plugin, list your dependency coordinates in the build .sbt, then run `sbt assembly`, then point your `SPARK_CLASSPATH` to the resulting fat jar.  This way sbt does the hard work of downloading and tying jars together rather than you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory under spark-home like:

> ~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/ext-jars/

for all external jar files and put all the jar files in that directory

Add following lines in spark-defaults.conf

> spark.driver.extraClassPath ~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/ext-jars/*
>   spark.executor.extraClassPath ~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/ext-jars/*