# Spark SQL: TwitterUtils Streaming fails for unknown reason

Tags: apache-spark, twitter-util

I am using the latest Spark master and additionally, I am loading these jars:
 - spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 - twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
 - twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar

My simple test program that I execute in the shell looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "jXgXF...")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "mWPvQRl1....")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "26176....")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "J8Fcosm4...")

var ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
var tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
var statuses = tweets.map(_.getText)
statuses.print()

ssc.start()
```

However, I won't get any tweets. The main error I see is

```
14/08/04 10:52:35 ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StatusListener;)V
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
    ....
```

And then for each iteration:

```
INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies.
How can I verify that my twitter credentials are correctly recognized?
Might there be another jar missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` should always cause you to ask whether you are running with the same versions of libraries and classes that you compiled with.

If you look at the pom.xml file for the Spark examples module, you'll see that it uses twitter4j 3.0.3. You're bringing incompatible 4.0.2 with you at runtime and that breaks it.

Comment: I have downloaded 3.0.3 from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j. Now the error changes to `Exception in thread "Thread-55" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/StatusListener`


How can I confirm which version is actually required? The ScalaDoc does not mention anything in that direction.

Comment: @Helm - It would be nice if the docs explicitly called this out, but I don't think they do anywhere. The next best thing would be to [ask the devs directly](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/What-version-of-twitter4j-should-I-use-with-Spark-Streaming-td9352.html). (Tathagata is the lead on Spark Streaming.) I called this out and linked to it in my answer to [your other question about using TwitterUtils](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085128/using-twitterutils-in-spark-shell/25088392#25088392).

Comment: Yeah, I will add this to the programming guide documentation.
Added to this JIRA for Spark 1.1 release 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2419?filter=12327885

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sean Owen has given the good reason, after I add two dependency files on the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In this way we change the default twitter4j version from 4.0.x to 3.0.x (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core), then the incompatible problem will be solved.